# make a list and print them out(Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I try to create a constructor first so I could use it again and again then I wanna print all person's information out but I can't finish this code could anyone help me and please write down your thought process thanks !!

```
function profession(name, skill, year) {
  this.name = name;
  this.skill = skill;
  this.years = years;
}
var Shen = new profession("Shen", "Javascript, nodejs", "0.3");
var Allen = new profession("Allen", "C, python", "20");
var Amy = new profession("Amy", "PHP, ruby", "3");
var jobHunting = [shen, Allen, Amy];

function list(person) {
  document.write("The expert is: " + person.name + " his skill is " + person.skill + " with " + person.year + " years experience.");
}

function findAll() {
  for (var i = 0; i < jobHunting.length; i++) {
    list(jobHunting[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Just call `findAll()`. Although you should really switch out `document.write` for `console.log` and look in your console (hit F12)

Comment: You should also capitalise `shen` in the array.

Comment: thanks it's really helpful

Answer (score 0):

There are a few typos.

```
    function profession(name, skill, years) {
      this.name = name;
      this.skill = skill;
      this.years = years;
    }
    var Shen = new profession("Shen", "Javascript, nodejs", "0.3");
    var Allen = new profession("Allen", "C, python", "20");
    var Amy = new profession("Amy", "PHP, ruby", "3");
    var jobHunting = [Shen, Allen, Amy];

    function list(person) {
      console.log("The expert is: " + person.name + " his skill is " + person.skill + " with " + person.year + " years experience.");
    }

    function findAll() {
      for (var i = 0; i < jobHunting.length; i++) {
        list(jobHunting[i]);
      }
    }
    findAll() {
      for (var i = 0; i < jobHunting.length; i++) {
        list(jobHunting[i]);
      }
    }
```